# How to detach a LocalDB (SQL Server Express) file in code

Tags: localdb

When using LocalDB .mdf files in deployment you will often want to move, delete or backup the database file.
It is paramount to detach this file first as [simply deleting it will cause errors because LocalDB still keeps a registration of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275054/ef5-cannot-attach-the-file-0-as-database-1/15832184#comment23237296_15832184).

So how is a LocalDB .mdf file detached in code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to string together the answer from several places, so I wil post it here:
[Mind, manually detaching the .mdf file from Visual Studio is possible after manually deleting it before detachment by going through SQL Server Object Explorer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275054/ef5-cannot-attach-the-file-0-as-database-1/15832184#comment23237296_15832184)

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Detach a database from LocalDB. This MUST be done prior to deleting it. It must also be done after a inadvertent (or ill advised) manual delete.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dbName">The NAME of the database, not its filename.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub DetachDatabase(dbName As String)
    Try
        'Close the connection to the database.
        myViewModel.CloseDatabase()

        'Connect to the MASTER database in order to excute the detach command on it.
        Dim connectionString = String.Format("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim cmd = connection.CreateCommand
            '--Before the database file can be detached from code the workaround below has to be applied.
            'http://web.archive.org/web/20130429051616/http://gunnalag.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/fix-cannot-detach-the-database-dbname-because-it-is-currently-in-use-microsoft-sql-server-error-3703
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", dbName)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '--
            '--Now detach
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", dbName)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '--
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Do something meaningful here.    
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and was thinking of how to deal with it.

There are 3 approaches.

1. Detach at the end of (or during) working with database

   I didn't find the way to *close* connection in *LinqToSQL*, but actually it is not needed. Simply execute the following code:

   ```
    var db = @"c:\blablabla\database1.mdf";
    using (var master = new DataContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        master.ExecuteCommand(@"ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", db);
        master.ExecuteCommand(@"exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", db);
    }
   ```

   and make sure nothing will try to query `db` after (or you get it attached again).
2. Detach on start

   Before you made any connection to `db`, detaching is as simple as:

   ```
    var db = @"c:\blablabla\database1.mdf";
    using (var master = new DataContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
        master.ExecuteCommand(@"exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", db);
   ```

   This suit very well to my needs, because I do not care about delay to start application (because in this case I will have to attach to `db` always), but it will fix any kind of

   > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'c:\blablabla\database1.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.

   which occurs, if database file is delete and you try to create it programmatically

   ```
    // DataContext
    if (!DatabaseExists())
        CreateDatabase();
   ```
3. Another way

   You can also run command line tool `sqllocaldb` like this:

   ```
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo("sqllocaldb", "stop v11.0");
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    using (var stop = Process.Start(start))
        stop.WaitForExit();
    start.Arguments = "delete v11.0";
    using (var delete = Process.Start(start))
        delete.WaitForExit();
   ```

   It will stop the server, detaching all databases. If you have other application using *LocalDB*, then they will experience attaching delay next time when they try to do query.

Comment: For "Detach on start" I receive: "User does not have permission to alter database '@p0', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.

ALTER DATABASE statement failed."

Any idea?

Comment: @fschricker, Yup. You are not detaching on start. Database is already opened somewhere in your application.

Comment: I was running the code in my unit test [ClassInitialize] so I was assuming the db be closed (fyi: using sqllocaldb is working ok).
But I was watching `localdb` via MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio; maybe that tool was having an open connection?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for EntityFramework Core 1.0

As you see the database name can be used with its full file path.

```
var dbf = fileDlg.FileName;
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
options.UseSqlServer($@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=master;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Integrated Security=True");
using (var master = new DbContext(options.Options))
{
     master.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [{dbf}] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
     master.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"exec sp_detach_db '{dbf}'");
}
```