# error cannot find path specified - NuGet - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

Can anyone help me fix this error? I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC

> Warning    1   The file '..\ProjectX.Data.CF\DbContextDatabase.cs' could not be added to the project.  Cannot add a link to the file C:\Anže\Programi\ProjectXService\ProjectX.Data.CF\DbContextDatabase.cs. This file is within the project directory tree.   ProjectX.Data.CF
>
> Error  2   The system cannot find the path specified.  WebPortal (WebPortal\WebPortal)
>
> Error  3   The command ""C:\Anže\Programi\ProjectXService.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Anže\Programi\ProjectXService\WebPortal\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Anže\Programi\ProjectXService\ "" exited with code 3.    WebPortal (WebPortal\WebPortal)

I tried:

- clearing package cache
- Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build" is checked.
- clean solution

Something has got to be wrong with the database because I cannot run old "working" version of a project too.

EDIT:
I tried deleting database using the answer here:
[How to re-create database for Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304058/how-to-re-create-database-for-entity-framework)
but I stopped at step 6 because I cannot run commands in PackageManagerConsole  - it needs build, but I cannot build the project because of this error

Answer (score 0):

Check your registry in this location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

There could be an AutoRun key for something called `ansicon` - removing that could fix your problem.

Comment: TY for your answer. Under Command processor I only have (Default), CompletionChar, DefaultColor, EnableExtensions, PathCompletionChar