# EF Code First Project Doesn't Create AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles etc Tables after changing DB Connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've finished an EF Code First Project with a SQL Express database in a lab environment.

Once the project is done, I've changed the DB Connection String to connect to the new Production SQL Express Database.

Now, I have got the Model tables generated automatically but the AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles etc. are not generated automatically. I am a new learner and I need your help to know how I can get the tables back in the database.

If I do update-database from the Package Manager Console, I get:

```
Error Number:4902,State:1,Class:16
Cannot find the object "dbo.AspNetUsers" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

And also if you could explain to me how the migration works for Identity tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Took backup of all my work

2) Deleted Migration Folder

3) Using SQL Management Studio, From the Production Server, Deleted the Database

4) From Package Manager Console

```
Enable-Migrations -Force
Add-Migration init
Update-Database
```

You know what, all the tables are back on production database now :-)
Thanks to Lin from
[How to re-create database for Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304058/how-to-re-create-database-for-entity-framework)

Hopefully this question/answer will help someone else like me

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just as a comment, `Enable-Migrations` is now obsolete in EF Core. just start with `Add-Migration`

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup.
Delete migration folder.
Delete db.
open package manager console > type
Add-Migration "initail migration" >  hit enter > type update-Database 
then you good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the Database, you can delete only these tables:

`__MigrationHistory, 
AspNetRoles, 
AspNetUserClaims, 
AspNetUserLogins, 
AspNetUserRoles`

then delete the Migration folder and finaly from you PM console:

```
Enable-Migrations -Force
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```